# Firebase hosting Access-Control-Allow-Origin for app engine URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am hosting a single page app on Firebase hosting and I need to allow cross domain request to app engine. App is hosted at project-id.firebaseapp.com and the app engine service on project-id.appspot.com. I red the [deployment documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#section-full-firebasejson) and there is no example how to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for URL.

Here is what my firebase.json looks like:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/server/:rest*",
        "destination": "https://app-id.appspot.com/:rest*",
        "type": 301
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/views/**",
        "destination": "/views/**"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [ {
      "source" : "https://app-id.appspot.com/registration/generate",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

I've tried to set the CORS using gsutils but it didn't help as well:

Here is my cors.json

```
[
    {
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600, 
        "method": ["GET", "POST"], 
        "origin": ["https://project-id.appspot.com/"]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance

SOLUTION:

If all you want is to allow CORS on static files then setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in app.yaml is enough. This header is not allowed to be in app.yaml on dynamic requests so you'll have to add it programatically.

If your request is a simple one then the following code works:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    resp.getWriter().append("Response");

}
```

However if your request is pre-flighted you'll have to override the doOptions method and add the appropriate headers:

```
@Override
protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
}

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    resp.getWriter().append("Response");
}
```

[Here](https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png) is a helpful diagram which clarifies CORS implementation on server:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your firebase.json does not control appspot.com files and can't be used to modify headers from your app engine service. Here, you've tried to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on `https://app-id.appspot.com/registration/generate`. That's not going to work since that's not a page hosted at Firebase Hosting.

Instead, the way you would add a header to a Firebase page would be to put it in the firebase.json like so:

```
"headers": [ {
  "source" : "index.html",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value" : "*"
  } ]
} ]
```

But that's not going to help with the CORS issue, since it needs to be in place [on the returned resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

It looks like you can put it into your app.yaml under `handlers` based on [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appref).

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mygame.appspot.com
```

Also, you can add this programatically. As explained on enable-cors.org, here are some script implementations:

For Python-based applications in Google App Engine, the `self.response.headers.add_header()` method can be used, such as:

```
class CORSEnabledHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    self.response.out.write(self.dump_csv())
```

For Java-based applications, use `resp.addHeader()`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
  resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  resp.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
  resp.getWriter().append(csvString);
}
```

And for Go-based applications, use `w.Header().Add()`:

```
func doGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/csv")
  fmt.Fprintf(w, csvData)
}
```